# Spoof source IP/Port with DatagramPacket

Tags: java, udp, datagram, spoofing

Is there any way to spoof the source IP/Port of a `DatagramPacket` object in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw Socket is a term that'll help your search.

You can look at the following question:
[Best way to do RAW socket programming involving Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854961/best-way-to-do-raw-socket-programming-involving-java)

They recommend a raw-socket wrapper, [rocksaw](http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/).

Comment: Oh, didn't know raw socket programming was possible in Java! :] Thanks!

Comment: @Di-0xide It isn't. You need Java + Rocksaw + its JNI component, or one of the various Jpcaps and its JNI component.