# implement accept(SocketImpl s) and object copying

Tags: java, sockets, copy

I'm implementing a *Positive Acknowledgement and Retransmission* transport protocol in terms of *RAW sockets* and in such cases a subclass of `SocketImpl` is needed. When implementing `accept`method I need something like this:

```
protected void accept(SocketImpl s) {
    ...
    s.copy(socket);
}
```

where `socket` is an already computed `SocketImpl` object that must be copied to an **already initialized** `SocketImpl` object `s` .i.e I need a **mutable copy method** `s.copy(socket)` that would copy source `socket` to target `s`. I know there exists `Object clone()` but it returns a new Object and what I need is to mutate `s`.

BTW some of you think that **mutating** a parameter, in this case `s`, is a **broken design**. It's not the only example in Java standard libraries. `implAccept(Socket s)` of `ServerSocket` class is another example. But this is how Sun/Oracle engineers have designed it. I'd like to know **why this is such a bad design**

At first sight it would seem that it has some sense to provide for a generic shallow `target.copy(source)` where `target = souce.clone()` would be equivalent to `target = new TheClass(); target.copy(source)`; but since it doesn't exist (possibly for good reason, please explain) the only way to go is to **program a custom field-by-field copy method**.

Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: What is your ultimate intention? Extending `SocketImpl` (or any socket, for this matter) is rather unusual thing to do.

Comment: @Victor: though the name doesn't suggest it, SocketImpl is abstract. So extending it should be one of its most usual usages ;)

Comment: @DaveBall yes, but all 3 classes which extend it in JDK 1.6.33 are internal to JDK and 2 of them have native methods in them (meaning they are essentially part of JDK implementation not meant to be extended directly by application programmer). And going to `clone` or _copy_ socket is not a thing you supposed to do in Java. There's OS kernel for such things.

Comment: @Victor: FYI I'm implementing a transport protocol in terms of raw IP sockets so a SocketImpl subclass is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what this method is for and how it works. I've done this many times. The `SocketImpl` provided to `implAccept()` is for the newly accepted socket, not the `ServerSocket`. So you don't *need* a second copy. All you need to do is wrap this `SocketImpl` in a `Socket`, or your own derived class of `Socket`. There is even a `Socket` constructor provided for the purpose, curiously enough.

Comment: Perhaps I don't get it but... I'm trying to implement an educational Positive Ack & Retransmission protocol in terms of RAW sockets so it's mandatory to extend `SocketImpl`. Basically `accept` --calls--> `implAccept` --calls--> `getImpl().accept(SocketImpl s)`. This is the one I'm overriding. `s` is an **already created** object so I've no other way than mutating it. Please, as always, enlighten me if I'm wrong

Comment: @francesc you won't be able to override `accept` of SocketImpl in a meaningful way unless you use JNI. But if you going to use JNI, there's no need to extend JDK class. Seems like people use "rocksaw" java lib for raw sockets under java, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3854961/162634

Comment: @Victor: obviously I'm using JNI and a much simpler raw sockets interface than "rocksaw" for educational purposes

Comment: @francesc then I'm sorry for a white noise on my side, though, it would be beneficial for future responders if you could update your question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess **there is no standard `target.copy(source)` (i.e. mutable copy method)** since  it is needed much more seldomly than cloning:

- you need to decide (for your situation and for all your fields) individually, whether they should be copied or identical (just like cloning vs. deep cloning);
- you can usually make a design such that you just switch the reference you hold outside, so in your case, you could just switch to use the reference `s` instead of the current object everywhere, which is simpler and much more efficient. If you need copied values, this corresponds to cloning (or using a copy constructor);
- you can easily implement it by wrapping the parameter (object `s` in your case).

The last point also answers **your second question**: alternatively to field-by-field copying, you could implement a forwarding class that forwards all exported methods of SocketImpl to a wrapped core SocketImpl:

- use your current implementation class `C` as private implementation with `protected void accept(SocketImpl s)` just throwing an exception;
- write a forwarding class `D` that

  - wraps a SocketImpl (e.g. an object of `C`), held in private field `wrapped`
  - extends SocketImpl and forwards all of its methods but `accept` to `wrapped`
  - implements `protected void accept(SocketImpl s)` simply with `{ s.wrapped = this; }`;¹
- if you want all fields to be copied in certain situations, give `accept` a copied parameter, e.g. via `accept(s.clone())` (or clone within `accept` if you want copies in all situations);
- only give out objects of type `D`, such that the exception in `C` is never thrown.

---

¹ This implementation of `accept` only works for parameters of type `D`. Otherwise, this horrible design (of having to mutate the SocketImpl given as parameter) requires `accept` to use ugly techniques, such as reflection (see e.g. org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/harmony/luni/net/PlainSocketImpl.java.html).

Comment: First, in the same way there is `clone` with shallow copy semantics we could very well have a standard `target.copy(source)` which would shallow copy source to target. Second I'm not free to choose the design I want. In `accept(SocketImpl s)` `s` is an **already created** object (please see my answer to @EJP) and I need to modify it

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. Perhaps I don't still get it... but `s` is the **target of the copy, not the source** so I need to mutate it, doing `this.wrapped = s` doesn't modify `s` in any way

Comment: Hm, the api for accept only says "Accepts a connection." :( So you mean that the postcondition of this.accept(SocketImpl s) is, that the fields of s are set to the ones for this??? That sounds like an awful design (having to mutate fields of the other object). Are you sure you can't design it the other way around, i.e. that the methods only mutate this?

Comment: basically yes, `this` is of `ServerSocket` type, but has the needed info to update `s`. `implAccept(Socket s)` also expects to mutate `s`. This is how Sun engineers have thought about it :-)

Comment: what I don't understand in your answer is why reflection techniques are needed, it's a s simple as `accept(SocketImpl s) { s.create(true); s.setPort(port); s.setAddress(addr); ...}`

Comment: ok, I'm writing too fast...: `MySocketImpl si = s; s.create(true); si.setPort(port); si.setAddress(addr);` or `((MySocketImpl)s).setPort(port)` if you like...