# How to parse bytes to IP packet on the fly

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I created a client which send data via sockets to the proxy and the proxy resend it to the server. I would like to modyfi packet headers on the fly in the proxy.

In the proxy I see only bytes and I don't know where packets begin and end. I would like to parse bytes to IP packet on the fly and after that I will know where packets begin and end but I don't know how to do it.

Is it any library for this operation or maybe anybody has simpler idea for doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use TCP or UDP sockets, you need to use raw sockets to get at the lower layers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854961/best-way-to-do-raw-socket-programming-involving-java

Comment: ok, I understand but in the proxy I see bytes so I If I know where packets begin and end I will can to change some fields and recalculate the checksum and resend it. Why I cannot do this like that?

Comment: Do you see packet headers? No.  Do you want to see packet headers? Yes.  Then you need raw sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to send data via raw socket from the client or in proxy use it somehow?

Comment: Client doesn't know that proxy is looking at raw sockets vs TCP.